# Entity Framework Code First: Xref table

Tags: frameworks, many-to-many, entity

I need to create an XRef table as follow:

```
Person:
  PersonID
  Name

Attribute:
  AttributeId
  Name

PersonAttribute:
  PersonID
  AttributeID
  Value
```

In this way, every person will have many attributes with values for that specific person.

Database tables have been created successfully. PersonAttribute:has two foreing keys. One for Person and another one for Attribute.

When I insert the first record, everything works fine. I have my person, my attribute and the value for that relation in PersonAttribute. 
But when I try to insert a new relation between the existing Attribute and another Person, instead of using the existing Attribute, it´s creating a new one (with the same name)

So I have something Like:

```
  Person:
  1 Jon
  2 Mark

 Property:
  1 Weight
  2 Weight

 PersonAttribute:
   1 1
   2 2
```

This would be my class PersonAttribute

```
public class PersonAttribute
    {       
        [Required]
        public virtual Person Person{ get; set; }

        [Required]
        public virtual Attribute Attribute { get; set; }

        public string Value{ get; set; }      
    }
```

Any clue about what I´m missing?

Thanks